# Undefined index Error and query not running?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am getting this error

> Notice: Undefined index: maxvalid in C:\wamp\www\myproj\includes\func.php on line 26

and my code is

```
require("common.php");

$incquery = "select max($TabFld) as maxvalid from $TabName";

    $stmt = $db->prepare($incquery);
    $incresult = $stmt->execute();

    $row=$stmt->fetchAll();

    $maxvalid = $row['maxvalid'];

    if($maxvalid <> NULL)

    {            

            $incvalid=$row['maxvalid']+1;

    }


    return $incvalid;
```

I am using PDO to connect mysql and I never used it before. I always use `mysql_connect` to connect database and I cannot understand why I am getting this error.

I also debug the code and see that value is not coming in `$maxvalid` variable but it came when I use `mysql_connect`.

Comment: it's for my college project i get code of login system to my friend which uses PDO to connect database. THNX

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`fetchAll` returns an array of rows. Try just `fetch`

For future reference, if in doubt, [`var_dump`](http://php.net/var-dump) it.

Comment: Appreciated Thank you!